# Apple App Store - Submitting Same App on Tablet and Phone

Tags: air, cross-platform, store

I have used a cross platform framework to create 3 apps for iPad tablets thinking that I would never add a version for iPhone.  Eventually, I found enough time to create an iPhone version that is acceptable and would like to add them to the App Store.  My concern is how to do it since the iPhone and iPad apps are separate ipa's?  In an ideal situation, I would call them the same exact name and use the same exact icons, but I have a feeling that Apple will not allow this.  So my next thought was that I could call the iPhone version "MyApp for iPhone", but use the same icon to keep branding similar.

Surely someone else has run into this problem.  How do you release the same app for two different devices on the app store when it is two separate ipa packages, and try to keep the branding as similar as possible?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

For this there are two options.

1. Option 1 is to make the current app work for iPhone by adding checks at the start of the app and showing the appropriate UI ( I use this in most of my apps with Flex and AIR).
2. Option 2 is to upload a different app with "MyApp for iPhone" and make the icon a bit different to avoid rejecting during review.